# Parameter expansion bash

Tags: bash

I'm recursively counting lines in files whose format is given in command line as a parameter, e.g. *.txt... In this example I'm searching for all .txt files and counting their lines. Additionally, I have to echo input parameters. My problem is with echo, when I try "$1", it expands and echoes all the .txt files, also with '$1' it echoes $1... What I want is not to expand and just echo raw input, in this case *.txt.

EDIT:

I'm calling the script with 2 parameters, first is the starting directory of recursion, and the second one is the format of desired file type.

```
./script.sh test *.txt
```

Then, I need to echo both of the parameters and recursively count the lines of the files whose format is given with 2nd parameter

```
echo $1
echo $2

find /$1 -name "$2" | wc -l
```

This code isn't working currently, but I'm trying to fix parameter echo first.

Comment: Please show your code. It sounds like you are expecting `*.txt` to be passed to your script; however, the shell will expand that and instead pass the files that match the pattern to your script.

Comment: I've edited my post, please check it now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this just for your particular script. Don't try to make `./script.sh foo *.txt` work the way you want. It's not how shells works, and no other utilities do it.

Instead, you should do it the same way `find` and `grep` does it: simply require the user to quote:

```
./script.sh foo '*.txt'
```

When you do this, you can in script.sh use `$2` quoted to keep it as a pattern (like in your `find /$1 -name "$2" | wc -l`, or unquoted to expand it into multiple filenames, as in your `echo $2`.

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking about that, but I thought it could be solved my (wrong) way.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to disable `glob`ing (this is odd), you can set :

```
set -o noglob
```

To set this option back to off :

```
set +o noglob
```

But I don't know what you are really trying to do, but I feel you do it the wrong way. You should consider giving more explanations on the context

Comment: Is there more elegant solution, or this is the only way?

Comment: Did you see my edit? I have to count lines of all the files with format given in the 2nd parameter. 1st parameter is the starting directory, and it recursively goes into all subdirectories. And additionally I have to echo 2nd parameter